# How to show nested database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello I have a nested database "processing" which belongst to "shopping_process". However I want somehow to see the messages, which are saved in processing. How can I do that? If I go to http://localhost:3000/processings/index the Error: Couldn't find Processing with 'id'=index appears. Has somebody an idea?

**processings_controller.rb**

```
class ProcessingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_processing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /processings
  # GET /processings.json
  def index
    @processings = Processing.all
  end

  # GET /processings/1
  # GET /processings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /processings/new
  def new
    @processing = Processing.new
  end

  # GET /processings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /processings
  # POST /processings.json
  def create
    @processing = Processing.new(processing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @processing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @processing, notice: 'Processing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @processing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @processing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /processings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /processings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @processing.update(processing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @processing, notice: 'Processing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @processing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @processing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /processings/1
  # DELETE /processings/1.json
  def destroy
    @processing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to processings_url, notice: 'Processing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_processing
      @processing = Processing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def processing_params
      params.require(:processing).permit(:shopping_process_id, :shopping_list_id, :accepted, :responded, :message)
    end
end
```

**view/processings/index.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Processings</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @Processing.all.each do |processing| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', processing %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_processing_path(processing) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', processing, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Processing', new_processing_path %>
```

**models/processing.rb**

```
class Processing < ApplicationRecord
  # db associations
  belongs_to :shopping_process
  belongs_to :shopping_list

  # validations
  validates :shopping_list, :presence => true
end
```

Now here comes the code for the database "shopping_processes"
**shopping_processes_controller.rb**

```
class ShoppingProcessesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  layout 'shopping_process', only: [:shopper_show, :senior_show]

  # GET /shopping_processes/1
  # GET /shopping_processes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # POST /shopping_processes
  # POST /shopping_processes.json
  def create
    @shopping_process.status =nil
    @shopping_process.processed = nil

    puts params.inspect

    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_process.save
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_process, notice: 'Shopping process was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @shopping_process }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_process.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_processes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /shopping_processes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @shopping_process.update(shopping_process_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @shopping_process, notice: 'Shopping process was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @shopping_process }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @shopping_process.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /shopping_processes/1
  # DELETE /shopping_processes/1.json
  def destroy
    @shopping_process.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to shopping_processes_url, notice: 'Shopping process was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def shopper_show
    @shopping_process = ShoppingProcess.find(params[:id])

    @users = {}
    first = true
    @shopping_process.shopping_lists.each do |shopping_list|
      user = shopping_list.user
      @users[user.id] = {color: (first ? 'blue' : 'yellow'), name: user.firstname + ' ' + user.lastname}
      first = false
    end
  end

  def senior_show
    @shopping_process = ShoppingProcess.find(params[:id])

    @shopping_process.shopping_lists.each do |shopping_list|
      #if shopping_list.user == current_user
      #  @shopping_list = shopping_list
      #end
      @shopping_list = shopping_list
      #to show the correct shopping list uncomment the block above and remove the declartion underneath it
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_shopping_process
      @shopping_process = ShoppingProcess.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def shopping_process_params
      params.require(:shopping_process).permit(:user_id, :status, :appointed, :processed, :shopping_list_id, processings_attributes: [ :shopping_list_id, :message ])
    end
end
```

**views/shopping_processes/form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(shopping_process) do |f| %>
  <% if shopping_process.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(shopping_process.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this shopping_process from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% shopping_process.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :appointed %>
      <%= f.datetime_select :appointed %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :shopper %>
      <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, :readonly => true%>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :shopping_list_id %>
      <%= f.select :shopping_list_id, ShoppingList.accessible_by(current_ability).map{ |sl| [sl.name, sl.id] } %>
    </div>

    <!-- SUB FORM FOR NESTED RESOURCE : PROCESSINGS -->
    <%= f.fields_for :processings, @shopping_process.processings.build do |ff| %>
        <div>
          <%= ff.label :Begleiter %>
          <%= ff.select :shopping_list_id, ShoppingList.all.map{ |sl| [sl.user.firstname, sl.id]} , {:prompt => true} %>
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= ff.label :message %>
          <%= ff.text_field :message%>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <!-- Submit-->
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by nested databases? Do you mean Processing model establishes it's own connection to a different database than this rails application? Might be worth posting your model and a bit more of your stack trace.

Comment: I hope I can explain it right: there is a sub form for nested resource ("processings") in "shopping_processes". I want to somehow show the saved messages in "processings"